# how to vary the threshold voltage of a MOSFET for simulation in LTSPICE

Tags: ltspice

I have a MOSFET circuit with multi-threshold voltages. I am using TSMC MOSFET with 180nm technology. How to specify these voltages in LTSPICE for simulation. Please help.

Comment: THere is absolutely no reason this question is should be down voted nor vote to close.  It addresses a potentially confusing configuration issue that is common to all spice families.  The structure is overly flexible but very configurable, and is text based as befits the tools history.

Comment: @rawbrawb Yet another case of "If I don't want to answer this, I'm just going to try to get the question closed", I venture. Yes, let's all stay in our ivory towers and ensure the newcomers never enter.

Answer (score 1):

Spice model decks typically have different model instances and names within them.  It's simply a matter of calling the appropriate model for your transistor.  You will have to open the model file and find the calling instances for the different models within it.

Each foundry will typically have a different calling name so a general statement is not not possible.

For example in one foundry for NMOS transistors there are ne,ne3,ne3i,ne5,ne5i,nei models in the sub-sub- directory.

the ne has this at the top

- ".subckt ne d g s b w=1e-6 l=1e-6 ad .... "

which in turn is called by another file with this .

- ".include ./models/bsim3v3/ne.mod"

And then within the Spice instance of the model this is called:
[image]

NOTE: this is not LTspice but how spice simulators run in general.  LTSPice will implement some variation on this.  But the nested/hierarchical nature of the library calls are a fundamental feature.

The calling sequence can be confusing when there are different process splits and options.  Fast-Fast, Slow-Fast etc.

Answer (score 0):

In an integrated circuit, other device parameters also change when the threshold voltage changes -- e.g. if the reason for the VTH change is oxide thickness, then many other parameters that depend on this also change -- capacitances, gm etc.

However, if you want just a ballpark estimate of the effects on your circuit, just put a voltage source in series with the gate.